# Multiple Language: Alternate - Canonical Conflict Problem?

Tags: html, seo, metadata, meta-tags

I have a page with 3 languages. However, I have questions about alternate canonical. Is what I'm doing correct or incorrect?

My main language is English. My other pages are translations of the English page into different languages.
For the English homepage, my meta tags are as follows:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="x.com/" />
<link rel="alternate" href="x.com/" hreflang="en" />
<link rel="alternate" href="x.com/de" hreflang="de" />
<link rel="alternate" href="x.com/es" hreflang="es" />
<link rel="alternate" href="x.com/" hreflang="x-default" />
```

For the German page, it's like this:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="x.com/de" />
<link rel="alternate" href="x.com/" hreflang="en" />
<link rel="alternate" href="x.com/de" hreflang="de" />
<link rel="alternate" href="x.com/es" hreflang="es" />
<link rel="alternate" href="x.com/" hreflang="x-default" />
```

For the Spanish page:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="x.com/es" />
<link rel="alternate" href="x.com/" hreflang="en" />
<link rel="alternate" href="x.com/de" hreflang="de" />
<link rel="alternate" href="x.com/es" hreflang="es" />
<link rel="alternate" href="x.com/" hreflang="x-default" />
```

Should I use canonical in all of them? Is what I'm doing correct or false for Google?"

Comment: Heeey. Is there anyone to answer?

Comment: I think your implementation is absolutely correct. The canonical declaration is important and should exist on every page.

Comment: well on this page: <link rel="canonical" href="x.com/" />,
  Is it okay to use this tag?
<link rel="alternate" href="x.com/" hreflang="x-default" />

Comment: Yes, you can. With that note, I recommend using absolute links (https://x.com/) rather than relatives (x.com).